# Gzip a string in Zlib using C/C++

Tags: gzipstream, gzip, gzipinputstream, gzipoutputstream

I would like to use gzip from C++ (or C) to gzip a string. If possible, I would like to use zlib.

When I learned that I would have to use zlib to compress and uncompress, I Googled it for a few minutes and then quickly wrote a program to gzip a file and then ungzip it. However, I don't actually have any need to do that. I need to use gzip to compress and uncompress a string, not a file. I couldn't find much good documentation for using gzip on strings. Every example I find works with files.

Could someone show me a simple example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the [zlib usage examples](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) they create function to inflate and deflate a file. But those function reads the data from the file manually. Instead of reading the data from a file, you read from your string. Also read the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's built into Poco (C++ library/framework, lots of utilities, networking, what you have). Here's a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Poco/InflatingStream.h>
#include <Poco/DeflatingStream.h>
#include <Poco/StreamCopier.h>

int main() {

    std::ostringstream stream1;
    Poco::DeflatingOutputStream
      gzipper(stream1, Poco::DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
    gzipper << "Hello World!";
    gzipper.close();
    std::string zipped_string = stream1.str();
    std::cout << "zipped_string: [" << zipped_string << "]\n";

    std::ostringstream stream2;
    Poco::InflatingOutputStream
      gunzipper(stream2, Poco::InflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
    gunzipper << zipped_string;
    gunzipper.close();
    std::string unzipped_string = stream2.str();
    std::cout << "unzipped_string back: [" << unzipped_string << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The nice thing is that instead of the ostringstreams above, you could hook up the Poco gzipping streams to files etc..

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if there's also a way to use stream that goes directly into a file that reside on an existing zip archive. do you know if this can be done ?